Why does my custom instruction simulation run incorrectly？
After seeing this C function:
double clamp (double x ) { return x < 0 ? 0 : x > 1 ? 1 : x ; }
I want to design a custom instruction named 'clp' , it uses F extesnion. The instruction format I designed is as follows:
clp       rd rs1 rs2 rs3 rm 26..25=1 6..2=0x15 1..0=3
First , I add the MASK_CLP and MATCH_CLP to riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-binutils /include/opcode/riscv-opc.h.
Then, in riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-binutils/opcodes/riscv-opc.c I add the following content:
{"clp",        0, INSN_CLASS_D_INX,   "D,S,T,R",       MATCH_CLP|MASK_RM, MASK_CLP|MASK_RM, match_opcode, 0}, {"clp",        0, INSN_CLASS_D_INX,   "D,S,T,R,m",       MATCH_CLP, MASK_CLP, match_opcode, 0},
After that , I recompiled my toolchain.
To achieve command functionality, I want to simulate the clp instruction in Spike.So I firstly add MATCH_CLP and MASK_CLP in spike/riscv/encoding.h, then I make a file named clp.h in spike/riscv/insns, I add the following content:
require_either_extension('D', EXT_ZDINX);
require_fp;
softfloat_roundingMode = RM;
if(f64_lt(FRS1_D, FRS2_D)){
WRITE_FRD_D(FRS1_D);
}
else if(f64_lt(FRS3_D,FRS1_D)){
WRITE_FRD_D(FRS3_D);
}
else 
WRITE_FRD_D(FRS2_D);
set_fp_exceptions;
Then , in spike/riscv/riscv.mk.in file, I add this 'clp' instruction.
in spike/disasm/disasm.cc file , I add this DEFINE_FR3TYPE(clp);
Then I recompiled my spike.
I write a test C program named clamp.c:
`#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    double a=0.0;
    double b=1.0;
    double c=0.3;
    double d;
    asm volatile
    (
        "clp %[w], %[x], %[y], %[z]\n\t"
        : [w] "=f"(d)
        : [x] "f" (c), [y] "f" (a), [z] "f" (b)
    );
    printf("%f\n",d);
    return 0;
}`

But I can't use command spike pk clamp to simulate it. It prompts 'An illegal instruction was excuted!'
Sincerely looking forward to your help！
I have tried many times, but it failed, I sincerely need help,thanks!
